# compare array of string with json object property

Tags: powershell

This is how my Input looks like:

```
$AllDrives = '[
    {
        "DriveLetter":  "F",
        "FileSystemLabel":  "Drive_F",
        "AllocationUnitSize":  4096
    },
    {
        "DriveLetter":  "E",
        "FileSystemLabel":  "Drive_E",
        "AllocationUnitSize":  4096
    },
    {
        "DriveLetter":  "H",
        "FileSystemLabel":  "",
        "AllocationUnitSize":  65536
    },
    {
        "DriveLetter":  "I",
        "FileSystemLabel":  "",
        "AllocationUnitSize":  65536
    },
    {
        "DriveLetter":  "G",
        "FileSystemLabel":  "",
        "AllocationUnitSize":  65536
    }
]' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I want to compare another array with $AllDrives and return those elements from another array where DriveLetter is not matching with them.

```
$StandardDrives = @("E","F","G","H","I","J","K")
```

How do I accomplish this in (PowerShell way) without running two loops ?

Expected output is `@("J","K")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` and take advantage of property enumeration:

```
$StandardDrives |Where-Object {$_ -notin $AllDrives.DriveLetter}
```

When PowerShell sees that the `$AllDrives` array object does not have a `DriveLetter` property, it'll automatically enumerate the values of `DriveLetter` on the individual array items instead, and the expression `$AllDrives.DriveLetter` thus expands to an array equivalent to `@('F','E','H','I','G')`

Comment: Nicely done. Re terminology: Regrettably, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties#properties-of-scalar-objects-and-collections) do not give the feature an official name. While the term _property enumeration_ is reasonable, the more general term is _member_ enumeration, given that the feature also works with _methods_. _Member enumeration_ is indeed the term the person who actually implemented the feature coined in the [blog post announcing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/).

Comment: @mklement0 The term "property enumeration" pre-dates "member enumeration" by 1 month then - it's the term used in the ["New Features in Windows PowerShell 3.0"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/whats-new/what-s-new-in-windows-powershell-50?view=powershell-7.2#windows-powershell-language-enhancements) - part of the on-box documentation released with Windows Server 2012, RC build of which dropped in mid-May 2012 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Good to know. But this is isn't a who-came-first issue. If _member_ doesn't make sense to you as the proper _abstraction_ encompassing both _properties_ and _methods_, then ¯\_(ツ)_/

Comment: The larger point is: The feature doesn't have an official name in the docs (blog posts don't count), but _it should_. I've tried to make the docs team introduce one, to no avail. In other cases, they did - whether I liked the name ultimately chosen or not ("intrinsic members"). In the absence of an official name, it would make sense for high-profile answerers here to agree on a name, hence my comment. Testy responses such as yours (a) suggest a lack of awareness that an agreed-upon term is important and (b) prevent reaching an agreement.

Comment: @mklement0 Fair point. FWIW I agree "member enumeration" is indeed the appropriate way to describe the _abstract_ operation, but I think in this specific case, "property enumeration" is a better label because I'm specifically showcasing implicit enumeration of properties (no second-level methods were invoked during the course of this answer ^_^). I really do appreciate you trying to establish some common ground in describing this core aspect of PowerShell's behavior, but I think the appropriate route is [through the docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/8437) :)

Comment: Thanks for creating the docs issue, @Mathias.

Answer (score 2):

here is yet another way to get the drive letters that are not in use. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- defines the list of possible drive letters
- uses the `.Where()` collection method to filter things
- checks to see if the possible letter is in the in-use letter collection
- outputs that to the success stream
  that can be captured to a $Var by assigning it to one.

the code ...

```
@('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k').Where({
    $_ -notin $AllDrives.DriveLetter
    })
```

output ...

```
j
k
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Compare-Object`:

```
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $AllDrives.DriveLetter -DifferenceObject $StandardDrives).InputObject
```

will return:

```
J
K
```